# Angular 2 - Return HTTP from inside a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Before each http call in my api service I want to check my local storage for an access token, then make the call once I have it. It looks like this

```
read(endpoint,params?) {

    var url: string = this.authService.apiUrl + endpoint, 
        headers: Headers = new Headers(),
        queryString: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    this.sessionService.getToken()
      .then((value) => {

        queryString.set('access_token', value);

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return this.http.get(url,{
          headers: headers, 
          search: queryString
        })
        .map(res => res.json())

      });


  }
```

And in my component I would have something like

```
  getData() {
    this.apiService.read('some endpoint')
      .subscribe(
        res => console.log(res),
        error => this.logError(error)
      )
  }
```

This was working until I put the http call inside of the .then after checking the local storage. So I think it is now nested incorrectly.

What is the correct way to appraoch this? And is there perhaps a more efficent way to grab my token from local storage in this set up? NOTE: I am using Ionic 2 which has its own function for checking local storage which returns a promise.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to convert the http observable to a promise or convert promise to an observable.

Observable to promise:

```
read(endpoint,params?) {

    var url: string = this.authService.apiUrl + endpoint, 
        headers: Headers = new Headers(),
        queryString: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    return this.sessionService.getToken() //return the outer promise
      .then((value) => {

        queryString.set('access_token', value);

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return this.http.get(url,{
          headers: headers, 
          search: queryString
        })
        .map(res => res.json()).toPromise() //use Observable.toPromise

      });


  }
```

To call use

```
this.apiService.read('some endpoint').then((data)=>{}).catch(err=>{})
```

Promise to Observable:

```
read(endpoint,params?) {

    var url: string = this.authService.apiUrl + endpoint, 
        headers: Headers = new Headers(),
        queryString: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    return Observable.fromPromise(this.sessionService.getToken())//convert to Promise and return chain.
      .switchMap((value) => {//use Observable.switchMap to move to second observable

        queryString.set('access_token', value);

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return this.http.get(url,{
          headers: headers, 
          search: queryString
        })
        .map(res => res.json())

      });


  }
```

From **RXJS 5.5** onwards:

Promise to Observable:

```
read(endpoint,params?) {

    var url: string = this.authService.apiUrl + endpoint, 
        headers: Headers = new Headers(),
        queryString: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    return fromPromise(this.sessionService.getToken())//import {fromPromise } from "rxjs/observables/fromPromise";
     .pipe(
      switchMap((value) => {//import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';

        queryString.set('access_token', value);

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return this.http.get(url,{
          headers: headers, 
          search: queryString
        })
      });
     );

  }
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks a lot `+1` :)