# Issue calling ngFor with API data

Tags: html, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to display all of the elements from a database call in my ionic app, but am getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://url/getAllProvs' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

below is my code for the html that I want populate with the API data:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button clear (click)="logout()">
      <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>All Patients</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="all-patients">
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of data1">
      {{item.firstName}}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

below is a picture of the postman get request of the data:
[image]

ts file:

```
export class AllPatientsPage {
  data1: any;
  loading: any;
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(public app: App, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private toastCtrl: ToastController, public navCtrl: NavController, public restService: RestService){
    this.getAllProvs();
    if(localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
  }

    getAllProvs(){
        this.restService.getAllProvs()
        .then(data => {
            console.log("all-patients.ts data");
            console.log(data);
            this.data1 = data;
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
}
```

below is rest-services method:

```
export class RestService {

 data1: any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RestServiceProvider Provider');
  }

    getAllProvs(){
        if(this.data1){
            return Promise.resolve(this.data1);
        }
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get('http://url/getAllProvs')
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log("rest-services.ts subscribe");
                this.data1 = data;
                console.log(data);
                resolve(this.data1);
            });
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the ts side of the component/page?

Comment: ok.. last question.. is `console.log(data);` giving right data?

Comment: @SurajRao I have added the ts file as well.  Now it no longer has the error, however it just prints a blank html

Comment: @SurajRao the `console.log()` statements are not printing anything in the console for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see a couple of issues in your code.

1. Since you are fetching the data asynchronously,`data1` will initially be an undefined object and `*ngFor` will throw an error.
   One way is to simply set initial value as empty array.

   ```
   data:any[]=[];
   ```
2. In order to convert an Observable to a Promise construct, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788534/4826457). Use `Observable.toPromise()`

Answer (score -1):

You could try convert the json data to an array and then use it.

```
 getBooks() 
      {
        this.isbnsource.getBooks(this.isbn).subscribe(
          data => { this.foundBooks = data.json();
     this.foundBooks = Array.of(this.foundBooks); 
           },
          err => console.error(err), 
          () => console.log('getBooks completed') 
          );
     }
```

Answer found in [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ngfor-only-supports-binding-to-iterables-such-as-arrays/59597)

Comment: am now getting the error `Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined` but am unsure how the data can be undefined when postman can pull the API data