# ionic 3 .then not waiting for promise result

Tags: ionic3

I have the following function:

```
loginPost(email, pin, pushToken) {

...

  this.getBaseURL()
    .then(baseURL => {
      console.log(baseURL);
      return this.http.post(baseURL + '/login', body, options)
        .map(res => res.json());
    });
}
```

and also

```
getBaseURL() {
  return this.storage.get('ipAddress')
    .then((ipAddress) => {
      return 'http://' + ipAddress + ':1000';
    });
}
```

My issue is that Ionic is attempting to the resolve `return this.http.post(baseURL + '/login', body, options).map(res => res.json());` before the `baseURL` gets resolve. I get the correct answer for the `console.log(baseURL);` but that is only happening after I get an error message saying that `return this.http.post(baseURL + '/login', body, options).map(res => res.json());` can't be subscribed to because it's undefined.

Comment: how are you calling `loginPost`? as a promise or as an observable?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788149/angular-2-return-http-from-inside-a-promise/42788534#42788534